# Perl conditional regex extraction

Tags: regex, perl

This conditional must match either `telco_imac_city` or `telco_hier_city`. When it succeeds I need to extract up to the second underscore of the value that was matched.

I can make it work with this code

```
if ( ($value =~ /(telco_imac_)city/) || ($value =~ /(telco_hier_)city/) ) {
    print "value is: \"$1\"\n";
}
```

But if possible I would rather use a single regex like this

```
$value = $ARGV[0];
if ( $value =~ /(telco_imac_)city|(telco_hier_)city/ ) {
    print "value is: \"$1\"\n";
}
```

But if I pass the value `telco_hier_city` I get this output on testing the second value

```
Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 19.
value is: ""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (<$input>){
    chomp;
    print "$1\n" if /(telco_hier|telco_imac)_city/;
}
```

Comment: OP wants to return "only up to the 2nd underscore of the value that was matched" (ie, `telco_hier_` or `telco_imac_`).

Answer (score 1):

[Perl capture groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups) are numbered based on the matches in a single statement. Your input, `telco_hier_city`, matches the *second* capture of that single regex (`/(telco_imac_)city|(telco_hier_)city/`), meaning you'd need to use `$2`:

```
my $value = $ARGV[0];
if ( $value =~ /(telco_imac_)city|(telco_hier_)city/ ) {
    print "value is: \"$2\"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$> ./conditionalIfRegex.pl telco_hier_city
value is: "telco_hier_"
```

Because there was no match in your first capture group (`(telco_imac_)`), `$1` is uninitialized, as expected.

**To fix your original code, use [FlyingFrog's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21865964/1454048):**

```
my $value = $ARGV[0];
if ( $value =~ /(telco_hier_|telco_imac_)city/ ) {
    print "value is: \"$1\"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$> ./conditionalIfRegex.pl telco_hier_city
value is: "telco_hier_"

$> ./conditionalIfRegex.pl telco_imac_city
value is: "telco_imac_"
```

Comment: What happens when `$value` is `telco_imac_` ?

Comment: @FlyingFrog Edited with (a slightly amended version of) your regex, thanks! The original part of the answer is helpful for OP to understand why the uninitialized warning was occurring.